# 'UseSerilog' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigureHostBuilder'

Tags: serilog-aspnetcore

I'm learning to logs exceptions in my ASP Net Core 6 by using Serilog, but why I'm getting the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ConfigureHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSerilog' 
and no accessible extension method 'UseSerilog' accepting a first argument of type 
'ConfigureHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?) ,
```

my program.cs

```
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
..
..

builder.Host.UseSerilog();

var app = builder.Build();
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You need the [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) package